# Why does not display the content of the label?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, label

So I have got a view with a label and I have got a ViewModel for it.

ViewModelBase

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual bool SetAndRaisePropertyChanged<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

This is how the ViewModel looks like:

```
  private string _balance = "1111$";
    public string Balance
    {
        get { return _balance; }
        set { SetAndRaisePropertyChanged(ref _balance, value); }
    }
```

And here is the view:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="monei_project.MainUpperView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:project"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:project.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="2200" FontFamily="Open Sans">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:MainUpperViewModel  x:Key="MainUpperViewModel"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainUpperViewModel}}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="22" Fill="#013542"></Rectangle>
    <Label  Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="16">Balance:</Label>
    <Label x:Name="lblBalance" Grid.Column="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Open Sans SemiBold" FontSize="24" Margin="55,28,45,33">
        <Label.Content>
            <Binding Path="Balance"/>
        </Label.Content>
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

In the designer, I can see the content of the label
[image]

But when I run the application, the label is empty
[image]

What is the problem?

I have already created some ViewModel, but there I worked with textboxes. We used INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and I am not sure how does it work, so my guess was, that it sets the content, but won't display it, because the label is not updating, so I tried to use the OnPropertyChanged function with a PropertyChangedEventHandler, what we used earlier to the other ViewModels, but it didn't work either, I do not know what can be wrong.

Comment: you understood well the issue and you were on the right path, see my answer for more ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the margin solved the problem. I guess the margin pushed out the label.

Answer (score 3):

There are some frameworks providing class already implementing the needed interfaces, if you want to do it yourself, here is a possibility:

First you have your ViewModelBase and all your ViewModels should inherit it

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual bool SetAndRaisePropertyChanged<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

then in your viewmodel you will declare your property like this:

```
private String _mBalance;
public String Balance
{
  get { return _mBalance; }
  set => SetAndRaisePropertyChanged(ref _mBalance, value);
}
```

[EDIT]: I want to keep the history of the answer, so check my edit below with full fonctionnal example:

Usually I split in more files, but i wanted to stay simple, so you need 2 files (I'm trying to apply MVVM pattern so i'm adding directories):
- Views\MainWindow.xaml
- ViewModels\MainWindowViewModel.cs

Views\MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow_DBG.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow_DBG"
        xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:StackOverflow_DBG.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="400">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodels:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding LabelTxt}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ValueTxt}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="Change Label" Command="{Binding ChangeLabel}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModels\MainWindowViewModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace StackOverflow_DBG.ViewModels
{
    public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected virtual bool SetAndRaisePropertyChanged<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
        private Action methodToExecute;
        private Func<bool> canExecuteEvaluator;
        public RelayCommand(Action methodToExecute, Func<bool> canExecuteEvaluator)
        {
            this.methodToExecute = methodToExecute;
            this.canExecuteEvaluator = canExecuteEvaluator;
        }
        public RelayCommand(Action methodToExecute)
            : this(methodToExecute, null)
        {
        }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (this.canExecuteEvaluator == null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                bool result = this.canExecuteEvaluator.Invoke();
                return result;
            }
        }
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this.methodToExecute.Invoke();
        }
    }

    class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private String m_LabelTxt = "Foo";
        public String LabelTxt
        {
            get { return m_LabelTxt; }
            set => SetAndRaisePropertyChanged(ref m_LabelTxt, value);
        }

        private String m_ValueTxt;
        public String ValueTxt
        {
            get { return m_ValueTxt; }
            set => SetAndRaisePropertyChanged(ref m_ValueTxt, value);
        }

        private RelayCommand m_ChangeLabel;
        public RelayCommand ChangeLabel
        {
            get { return m_ChangeLabel; }
            set { m_ChangeLabel = value; }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            ChangeLabel = new RelayCommand(() => {
                if (LabelTxt == "Foo")
                {
                    LabelTxt = "Bar ";
                }
                else
                {
                    LabelTxt = "Foo ";
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This way you also see how to bind button for example. Press the button to see that the update is well done.
If using same directories than me, remember to edit app.xaml to use `StartupUri="Views/MainWindow.xaml">` 
instead of

```
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This ViewModelBase was a really great idea, I just start to think in this way, when I am programming. So I created that BaseViewModel what you suggested with three function.

I used three function because I really do not understand how are these works.
I have got two function from your example, and I also add the function what we used earlier in this project. I will edit the post, you can see there. What are the functions doing? Still not working. Which function should I bind to which XAML property to get it work?

Comment: 2 issues, you shouldn't need the OnPropertyChanged, it's already handled by the code I provided. The really big issue in your modification is : set { SetAndRaisePropertyChanged(ref _balance, "1111$"); } you really need to keep the code I posted. the word value is a key word and means the value you provided to set yourt property. take my code and then you can set your property like a classical variable: Balance = "1111$";  if you want to initialize with a default value, you do it on the private part: private String _mBalance = String.Empty; for example

Comment: For the datacontext (you are setting it in the xaml) your way may work but I think you can do it better. Maybe tomorrow i can share more code if needed but try what I said, it should be ok.

Comment: Still not figured it out, how to get it work, so i would appreciate it.

Comment: Full example added ;)

Comment: I got syntactical error for this expression(set => SetAndRaisePropertyChanged(ref _balance, value)). Your solution gonna work, when I press the button, but to me it should to set the label text after the Login. This is an application where you can register, and after the login you can see there your budget balance. So when the login is succesful, the program should get the user's balance from the database, and that balance what I want to display on his main screen after the login. In this solution you set a command to the button, which will set up the content, but I want to do it automatically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183779/discussion-between-ame-and-mikitori).

Comment: @AME I answered on the chat, not sure if you saw it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you properly set the DataContext on the window/control to your view model? You need to set your DataContext before you are able to use bindings. And as such, you should probably use the proper way for binding:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Balance}" ... />
```

Edit:

Okay, I'll give you a concrete example of what I mean. Also, you're going to run into a lot of issues using a view model as a `StaticResource`. Why do I say this? Because once you start adding dependencies to your view model (accessing business logic, etc), you will need some form of dependency injection (DI) or a similar way to do so.

So you have your `ViewModelBase`, so I'll use that and not duplicate myself. Here's a simple view model:

```
public class AccountViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    string _balance = "1111$";

    public AccountViewModel(string accountNumber)
    {
        AccountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public string AccountNumber { get; }

    public string Balance
    {
        get { return _balance; }
        set { SetAndRaisePropertyChanged(ref _balance, value); }
    }
}
```

Here's the view code (`MainWindow.xaml`):

```
<Window x:Class="testProj.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding Balance}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code behind (`MainWindow.xaml.cs`):

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow(AccountViewModel dataContext)
    {
        DataContext = dataContext;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And for fun, the `App.xaml.cs` (set up for BuildAction - Page):

```
public partial class App
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new MainWindow(new AccountViewModel("123456789")).ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

This will show you what you are expecting, and display the Balance correctly. There are a few things you can try to see what your issue is:

1. Is there any information in the output window when debugging that tells you if a binding error is occurring?

Can you give a shorter version of your application showing all parts (i.e. a short project that duplicates the issue) and upload it somewhere?

Comment: I do not know what do you mean by DataContext, but I updated the the XAML code and you can see there how did I bind the ViewModel to the View.

Comment: Anyway I tried your code, and still not working, In my opinion it is doing the same.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. So the binding is works fine when I update the view, but when I first open the window, it won't display the initial value of the property, just after I trigger it with an update

Comment: Have you tried using the Live Visual Tree explorer in Visual Studio to inspect the label and see what its `Content` property is initially? What debugging steps have you taken to validate that the Balance property is initialized properly to have the value you've expected?

Comment: The margin was the problem. :)